# Can I use XPath functions with XPathNavigator?

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

I've got an XPathNavigator at the root of a document. Several levels down, there's a group of numeric values that I want to sum. I could always loop through the nodes and add them myself, but since I knew the XPath spec included a sum function, I decided to try to use that. I'm running into an error.

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathException - Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
```

Here's my code.

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(myLiteralXML));
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
string myXPath = "sum(/root/level1/level2/elementsToAdd)";
XPathNavigator sumNode = nav.SelectSingleNode(myXPath);
```

I expected `sumNode.Value` to give me my sum (as a string). But instead I get the exception listed above when I try to populate `sumNode`.

I know my XPath is valid (or at least XMLSpy says it is). Can I not use the XPath functions 
on an XPathNavigator? Am I just doing it wrong?

(Also, just curious, am I wasting my time on a dead-end approach nobody's using, and risking not being able to figure out a year from now what this is doing?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
XPathNavigator sumNode = nav.Evaluate(myXPath);
```

The [`XPathNavigator.Evaluate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.evaluate.aspx) method is defined as:

> Evaluates the specified XPath expression and returns the typed result.

as opposed to the `XPathNavigator.SelectSingleNode` method which is designed to only return nodes.

Comment: Never knew that was there. Thanks.